# Any chances that we can override the action of pulling down the status bar?

Tags: android, notifications

All I want is that, when users **pull down the status bar**, instead of seeing notifications or settings, they will **see an activity** of my app. If not then, can I use **2 fingers to pull down the status bar** and they'll see my activity, if still not, can I **pull down from the left/ right of the status bar** to do that stuff. I've seen several ROMs that allow users to do that. Can we do that with application?

Comment: This is part of the system UI. Custom ROMs can do this because they are altering code that is part of the system UI. Regular apps cannot do this.

Comment: Aw....ok. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible. There is no event that is fired, and no way to detect the action.